# Hiding base fields

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, mocking

I'm writing a stub implementation of the GroupPrincipal from System.DirectoryServices so I can unit test the code I'm writing that uses this class.  One of the properties I need to put test data into is a readonly property of the base class.  When the mock object makes its way to the application code, the application code has it cast as the base class and when it references that field it gets the base class reference instead of the one from my stub class.  Here's a unit test that illustrates the problem:

```
class ClassWithString
{
    private string _AttributeToTest;
    public string AttributeToTest { get { return _AttributeToTest; } }
}
class StubClassWithString : ClassWithString
{
    public string AttributeToTest { get { return "This is my string"; } }
}
[TestMethod]
public void TestStubClassWithStringCastToClassWithString()
{
    ClassWithString toTest = new StubClassWithString();
    Assert.IsNotNull(toTest.AttributeToTest);
}
```

This assertion will fail.  Is there anyway to use reflection or any other tricks to get the reference (cast as the base class) to return the value of the child class?  I'm trying to avoid adding another layer of abstraction like a wrapping class around the base class.

Comment: This field is public, you can set it from anywhere

Comment: Sorry, lazyberezovsky, I forgot an important detail.  I'm updating the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set private field value, then you can use following extension method:

```
public static T SetPrivateFieldValue<T>(this T target, string name, object value)
{
    Type type = target.GetType();
    var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
    var field = type.GetField(name, flags);
    field.SetValue(target, value);
    return target;
}
```

Usage:

```
ClassWithString toTest = new ClassWithString()
                              .SetPrivateFieldValue("_AttributeToTest", "Foo");
```

But I don't understand what you are trying to test this way. Internal implementation should stay internal.

Comment: Thanks Lazyberezovsky, I'll use this.  I know internal implementation should stay internal, but I need an object that looks and acts like an active directory principal without actually coming from active directory.  If you have a better idea of how to create stub items for this class I'm all ears, the class is system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.

Comment: @Segfault well, I'm not a fan of AD :) But I'd started with separating my application from AD implementation details. I.e. creating gateway which will hide all AD specific details. Then I'd mocked this gateway and tested my application classes.

Comment: @Segfault I tend not to mock code which I don't own. Maybe some integration tests will help you. Otherwise tests can be brittle and they will take lot of time to write and maintain